# Cypher query to find all relationship among multiple nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have a complex graph as shown in image below :

[image]

Here every relationship has a type value. I need to write a cypher query to find all relationships (with their type values) among given set of nodes (two or more). The nodes can be entered in any order, like x64->Linux->Oracle or Oracle->Linux->10.2.

**EDIT**

I am expecting output like this. All the combination of nodes with relationship name that links them.

1. For input : x64->Linux->Oracle

[image]

2. For input : Linux->64->Oracle->12c

[image]

**DATA**

Data can be accessed from https://www.dropbox.com/s/w28omkdrgmhv7ud/Neo4j%20Queries.txt?dl=0

**EDIT**
New Output format for input x64->Linux->Oracle

[image]

Comment: Can you post the resulting graph of `CALL apoc.meta.graph();` please? It renders your node and label structure, which helps us to provide the answer as concrete as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you're looking for only relationships directly connecting each pair of nodes in the set (as opposed to finding all multi-hop paths between pairs of nodes in the set), APOC Procedures has [apoc.algo.cover()](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_graph_algorithms_work_in_progress) for exactly this use case:

```
...
// assume `nodes` is the collection of nodes
CALL apoc.algo.cover(nodes) YIELD rel
RETURN rel
```

EDIT

As mentioned in my comment, your change to the requirements drastically changes the nature of the question.

You seem to want complete path results (directed), including nodes that are not in your input, and you want to ensure that the same `type` attribute is present for all relationships in the path.

This requires that we find the ordering of those nodes so we can identify a path between all of them. While we could find all possible permutations of the input nodes (for the order of traversal for the paths), I think we can get away with just finding permutations of 2 for the start and end nodes (by UNWINDING the collection twice and removing rows where the start and end node are the same). We'll want to first find all the input and output relationship types so we can use some set operations (output types of the start node intersected with input types of the end node intersected with all the (intersected) input and output types of the other nodes) to find the potential types that can possibly be present on relationships that can connect all the nodes.

From the remaining rows after this filtering we can match to the variable-length path that can connect all of those nodes, using only the types provided so that each path only traverses traverses relationships with a single type. Afterwards we filter to ensure that all the input nodes are in the path.

We'll assume the nodes are of type :Node with the property 'name'.

```
MATCH (entity:Entity) 
WHERE entity.key in ['Product','Version','BinaryType'] AND entity.value in ['pc','10.2','64']
WITH collect(entity) as nodes
UNWIND nodes as node
WITH nodes, node, [()-[r]->(node) | r.type] as inputTypes, [(node)-[r]->() | r.type] as outputTypes
WITH nodes, node, apoc.coll.toSet(inputTypes) as inputTypes, apoc.coll.toSet(outputTypes) as outputTypes
WITH nodes, collect({node:node, inputTypes:inputTypes, outputTypes:outputTypes}) as nodeData
UNWIND nodeData as start
UNWIND nodeData as end
WITH nodes, start, end, nodeData
WHERE start <> end
WITH nodes, start, end, apoc.coll.subtract(nodeData, [start, end]) as theRest
WITH nodes, start.node as start, end.node as end, apoc.coll.intersection(start.outputTypes, end.inputTypes) as possibleTypes, [data in theRest | apoc.coll.intersection(data.inputTypes, data.outputTypes)] as otherTypes
WITH nodes, start, end, reduce(possibleTypes = possibleTypes, types in otherTypes | apoc.coll.intersection(possibleTypes, types)) as possibleTypes
WHERE size(possibleTypes) > 0
UNWIND possibleTypes as type
MATCH path = (start)-[*]->(end)
WHERE all(rel in relationships(path) WHERE rel.type = type) 
 AND length(path) >= size(nodes) - 1 
 AND all(node in nodes WHERE node in nodes(path))
RETURN nodes(path) as pathNodes, type
```

To do this with both type and level, we need to collect both of them earlier in the query, so instead of dealing with just a type, we're dealing with a map of both the type and the level. This does make the query a bit more complex, but it's necessary to ensure that the paths provided have the same type and level for all relationships in the path.

```
MATCH (entity:Entity) 
WHERE entity.key in ['Product','Version','BinaryType'] AND entity.value in ['pc','10.2','64']
WITH collect(entity) as nodes
UNWIND nodes as node
WITH nodes, node, [()-[r]->(node) | {type:r.type, level:r.level}] as inputs, [(node)-[r]->() | {type:r.type, level:r.level}] as outputs
WITH nodes, collect({node:node, inputs:apoc.coll.toSet(inputs), outputs:apoc.coll.toSet(outputs)}) as nodeData
UNWIND nodeData as start
UNWIND nodeData as end
WITH nodes, start, end, nodeData
WHERE start <> end
WITH nodes, start, end, apoc.coll.subtract(nodeData, [start, end]) as theRest
WITH nodes, start.node as start, end.node as end, apoc.coll.intersection(start.outputs, end.inputs) as possibles, [data in theRest | apoc.coll.intersection(data.inputs, data.outputs)] as others
WITH nodes, start, end, reduce(possibles = possibles, data in others | apoc.coll.intersection(possibles, data)) as possibles
WHERE size(possibles) > 0
UNWIND possibles as typeAndLevel
MATCH path = (start)-[*]->(end)
WHERE all(rel in relationships(path) WHERE rel.type = typeAndLevel.type AND rel.level = typeAndLevel.level) 
 AND length(path) >= size(nodes) - 1 
 AND all(node in nodes WHERE node in nodes(path))
RETURN nodes(path) as pathNodes, typeAndLevel.type as type, typeAndLevel.level as level
```

Comment: Small note @InverseFalcon: I love the sophistication and elegance of your solutions. Every time again.

Comment: Brilliant, it worked like charm. But I need a different output. I have updated question with my output requirement. Can you please help on that.

Comment: The change to your requirements drastically changes the nature of the question. The nodes in your output are not the nodes in your input, so you aren't actually asking about the relationships that directly connect the inputs. You're asking for a much harder thing...you're asking for paths between the nodes involving other nodes with additional restrictions (though you haven't said if there are restrictions on relationship direction and type), and no concept of a starting place. Honestly I'm not sure how to approach this one.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I prepended below statement to your query to pass nodes

`match (entity:Entity) where entity.key in ['Product','Version','BinaryType'] and entity.value in ['pc','10.2','64']
with collect(entity) as nodes`

But it is giving error : 

`Neo.ClientError.Statement.TypeError: Type mismatch: expected a map but was List{Map{node -> (146), inputTypes -> List{}, outputTypes -> List{String("domain_database_6"), String("domain_database_5"), String("domain_database_4"), String("domain_database_3"), ...`

Comment: Okay, got something working, adjusted answer accordingly. Inputs are just nodes, the query will find the relationship types that are in common for all relationships in the path between all the nodes. You will of course want to make sure you have an index in place so the lookup of your starting nodes is quick.

Comment: @InverseFalcon, Need one more help. The relationship contains one more property "`level`" along with "`type`". I want to extract this property as well. How do I adjust query?

Comment: @InverseFalcon, I am waiting for your response, please help.

Comment: Do you mean that `level` on relationships also has to be the same across the entire path along with `type`?

Comment: `level` is another property that exists on each relationship along with `type'. I need this property also to be part of output.

Comment: Right, but the output so far is the list of nodes in the path and the common type. Are you asking for a list of the levels for all relationships in the path as well, or are you looking to restrict paths so that the level is in common, the same way we did with type, and to show the single level used in all the relationships of the path?

Comment: I have added a pic for new output format. please check.

Comment: Okay, so paths where both the type and the level are the same for all relationships in the path.

Answer (score 1):

### Remarks

Before I render the solution and result, I would like to suggest a revision of your model.

- If not already done, introduce different node types in the form of labels (`Architecture`, `Software`, `SoftwareVersion`, etc.) which will make your data retrieval much easier.
- Depending on the number of source databases `domain_database_n` and the parallel `SUPPORTS` relationships resulting from it, the use of [multiple labels for a node](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/create/#create-create-a-node-with-multiple-labels) could be clearer and more performant. A bigger amount of relationships would be superfluous in this case.
- Neo4j doesn't have a focus on searching and filtering of relationship properties. Modeling those attributes as node or property of a node is significantly more performant, especially for large graphs.
- Consider the [Neo4j naming conventions](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/naming/).

### Your graph / initial situation

For the ease of possible further answers and solutions I note my graph creating statement:

```
CREATE
  (pc:UntypedNode {name: 'PC'})-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_1'}]->(tenDotTwo:UntypedNode {name:'10.2'}),
  (pc)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_2'}]->(tenDotTwo),
  (pc)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_3'}]->(tenDotTwo),
  (pc)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_4'}]->(tenDotTwo),
  (pc)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_5'}]->(tenDotTwo),
  (pc)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_6'}]->(tenDotTwo),
  (pc)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_7'}]->(tenDotTwo),
  (tenDotTwo)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_1'}]->(linux:UntypedNode {name:'Linux'}),
  (tenDotTwo)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_2'}]->(linux),
  (tenDotTwo)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_3'}]->(linux),
  (tenDotTwo)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_4'}]->(linux),
  (tenDotTwo)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_5'}]->(linux),
  (tenDotTwo)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_6'}]->(linux),
  (tenDotTwo)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_7'}]->(linux),
  (linux)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_1'}]->(sevenDotZero:UntypedNode {name:'7.0'}),
  (linux)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_2'}]->(sevenDotZero),
  (linux)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_3'}]->(sevenDotZero),
  (linux)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_4'}]->(sevenDotZero),
  (linux)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_5'}]->(sevenDotZero),
  (linux)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_6'}]->(sevenDotZero),
  (linux)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_7'}]->(sevenDotZero),
  (sevenDotZero)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_1'}]->(x64:UntypedNode {name:'x64'}),
  (sevenDotZero)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_2'}]->(x64),
  (sevenDotZero)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_3'}]->(x64),
  (sevenDotZero)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_4'}]->(x64),
  (sevenDotZero)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_5'}]->(x64),
  (sevenDotZero)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_6'}]->(x64),
  (sevenDotZero)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_7'}]->(x64),
  (x64)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_1'}]->(sixtyFour:UntypedNode {name:'64'}),
  (x64)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_2'}]->(sixtyFour),
  (x64)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_3'}]->(sixtyFour),
  (x64)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_4'}]->(sixtyFour),
  (x64)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_5'}]->(sixtyFour),
  (x64)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_6'}]->(sixtyFour),
  (x64)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_7'}]->(sixtyFour),
  (sixtyFour)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_1'}]->(sqlServer:UntypedNode {name:'SQL Server'}),
  (sixtyFour)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_2'}]->(sqlServer),
  (sixtyFour)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_3'}]->(sqlServer),
  (sqlServer)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_1'}]->(year2014:UntypedNode {name:'2014'}),
  (sqlServer)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_2'}]->(year2016:UntypedNode {name:'2016'}),
  (sqlServer)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_3'}]->(year2017:UntypedNode {name:'2017'}),
  (year2014)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_1'}]->(s:UntypedNode {name:'S'}),
  (year2016)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_2'}]->(s),
  (year2017)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_3'}]->(s),
  (sixtyFour)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_4'}]->(oracle:UntypedNode {name:'Oracle'}),
  (sixtyFour)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_5'}]->(oracle),
  (sixtyFour)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_6'}]->(oracle),
  (sixtyFour)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_7'}]->(oracle),
  (oracle)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_4'}]->(release12c:UntypedNode {name:'12c'}),
  (oracle)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_5'}]->(release12gr2:UntypedNode {name:'12gR2'}),
  (oracle)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_6'}]->(release12cr:UntypedNode {name:'12cR'}),
  (oracle)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_7'}]->(release12cr1:UntypedNode {name:'12cR1'}),
  (release12c)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_4'}]->(s),
  (release12gr2)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_5'}]->(s),
  (release12cr)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_6'}]->(s),
  (release12cr1)-[:SUPPORTS {type: 'domain_database_7'}]->(s);
```

### Solution

```
MATCH (n:UntypedNode)
  WHERE n.name IN $names
WITH collect(n) AS nodes
UNWIND nodes AS n
UNWIND nodes AS m
WITH *
  WHERE id(n) < id(m)
MATCH path = allShortestPaths((n)-[relation*..10]-(m))
  WHERE ALL(x IN relation
    WHERE x.type = $relationshipName)
WITH
  collect({ path: path, pathLength: length(path) }) AS data,
  max(length(path)) AS maxLength
WITH [row IN data WHERE row.pathLength = maxLength] AS rows
UNWIND rows AS row
RETURN row.path AS path;
```

with parameters:

- "nodeNames": `['Oracle', 'Linux', '10.2']`
- "relationshipName": `'domain_database_4'`

### Explanation:

- line 1-2: identification of the given starting nodes
- line 3-5: create two sets of individual rows for the starting nodes
- line 6-7: take only one direction of each relationship and exclude node self references
- line 8: compute all shortest paths between both sets of starting node rows until a length of 10 relationships
- line 9-10: filter all resulting paths regarding relationships with specified type (parameter relationshipName)
- line 11-15: filter for the longest „shortest path“, omitting part paths
- line 16: render the resulting path(s)

### Result

```
╒═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"path"                                                     │
╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│[{"name":"10.2"},{"type":"domain_database_4"},{"name":"Linu│
│x"},{"name":"Linux"},{"type":"domain_database_4"},{"name":"│
│7.0"},{"name":"7.0"},{"type":"domain_database_4"},{"name":"│
│x64"},{"name":"x64"},{"type":"domain_database_4"},{"name":"│
│64"},{"name":"64"},{"type":"domain_database_4"},{"name":"Or│
│acle"}]                                                    │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

[image: graph]

Comment: I had already tried somewhat similar approach, but queries were taking very long time to execute